# Access to an embedded in-memory HSQLDB instance

Tags: hsqldb, in-memory-database

My question relates to **in-memory embedded HSQLDB**. Say I have one database instance called **`my_db`**.

I assume the following code allows to access the above database instance:

```
org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing.main(new String[] { "--url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:my_db", "--noexit" });
```

- Can I access the database from wherever I want provided it is in the same JVM process?
- In which specific part of the memory is the data held?
- More generally, what rules and restrictions determine from where and how I can access the database instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Can I access the database from wherever I want provided it is in the same JVM process?

A: Yes you can.

Q: In which specific part of the memory is the data held?

A: In the memory heap of the JVM process

Q: More generally, what rules and restrictions determine from where and how I can access the database instance?

A: The rule is only one JVM process can access a single embedded database. If you need access from more than one JVM, then you need to run an HSQLDB Server instance.